# Removing BOM characters from <HtmlElement> Python

Tags: python, python-requests, byte-order-mark

I am trying to load the html markup from a URL this way, and then run some xpath queries, but the page source is loaded with BOM, how to I remove them before I run the xpath?

```
session = requests.Session()

page = session.get(url)

page_data = lxml.html.fromstring(page.text)
```

Output:

```
 u'Re\ufeffverse \ufeffFleece \ufeffHoo\ufeffded S\ufeffwea\ufefftshi\ufeffrt'
```

Comment: `page_data = page_data.replace(u'\ufeff', '')`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey this is what i get TypeError: Argument 'old_element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got unicode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session = requests.Session()

page=session.get(url)

page_data = lxml.html.fromstring(page.text)

float=lxml.html.tostring(page_data).replace('&#65279;', '')

page_data = lxml.html.fromstring(float)
```

Comment: ...why convert the text into an lxml node, then convert that node back into text to remove the BOM, and then convert the text to an lxml object _again_? Just do `page_data = lxml.html.fromstring(page.text.replace('&#65279;', ''))`